# Error screen with white background

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

When getting an exception with React Native on iOS, I get this error screen with white background. You can see by the tapped cell that it actually has the exception stack, only with a white background. Not sure why's happening, but is there a way to fix? On Android the screen has red background (hence working as expected.)

Running React Native 0.48.3.

[image: React Native Exception Screen]

Comment: Found a solution @dccarmo?

Comment: @Forres I haven't but, ever since I started running my app on iPhone X emulator, it stopped appearing. So maybe try running in different simulators?

Comment: Found out an answer @dccarmo (At least for my situation), added an answer below 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206139/error-screen-with-white-background/46914800#46914800

Answer (score 3):

Found out why it was happening (At least in my case)

My team implemented a new launch screen as a `.storyboard` file, and that was causing the white screen. 
If you change that launch screen for a `.xib` file it should work.

Comment: storyboard... :)

Comment: Fixed! Thanks @ofer2980

Answer (score 1):

I can't figure out how to solve this issue, but a work around that I found is to enable `Debug > Color Blended Layers` for the Simulator. This gives some contrast to the screen, allowing you to make out the text. This problem happens to me on the iPhone X simulator, I haven't tested the other devices.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that react-native-navigation failed to load the Storyboard file caused the window to be loaded with empty rootViewController. It is now fixed in react-native-navigation latest version.