# All the error is hidden by a white background in react-native

Tags: react-native

This is the screenshot of my application when it is throwing error. However, when I pressed on the screen, the error will appear in grey texts.

[image]

I am using CocoaPods to import react-native to my app. Here is my podfile:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

# platform :ios, '10.0'

target '{MY_PROJECT_NAME}' do
  rn_path = '../node_modules/react-native'
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'

  pod 'yoga', :path => '../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga'
  pod 'React', path: '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
    'Core',
    'RCTActionSheet',
    'RCTAnimation',
    'RCTGeolocation',
    'RCTImage',
    'RCTLinkingIOS',
    'RCTNetwork',
    'RCTSettings',
    'RCTText',
    'RCTVibration',
    'RCTWebSocket',
    'BatchedBridge',
    'DevSupport'
  ]

  # Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core'

  # pod 'FirebaseMessaging'
  pod 'react-native-maps', path: rn_maps_path
  pod 'GoogleMaps'  
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', path: rn_maps_path

  target '{MY_PROJECT_NAME}-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths

    pod 'CodePush', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-code-push'

    pod 'RNBackgroundGeolocation', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation'

    pod 'RNBackgroundFetch', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-background-fetch'

    pod 'ReactNativePermissions', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-permissions'

  end

  target 'DolphinTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "react-native-google-maps"
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'No'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure whether it is because I missed some subspec of react-native.

Comment: It's already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46206139/error-screen-with-white-background)! Let me know if it doesn't work for you

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I was upgrading react native but I keep the old version for now. So, I can’t verify it at this moment. I will check this when I need to upgrade the version later. Thanks anyway.

Comment: you are welcome